# Android Ad loads during animation

Tags: android, admob

I am loading an ad using AdMob in Android. The ad request is done in background, but if the user starts a translate animation and the ad is loaded and shown during this animation, the animation loses it's fluidity ( instead of a smooth translation it starts jumping ). Now a simple logic will forbid the ad to display if an animation is in progress. Do you have any idea how to implement this logic? Or another idea is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vlad.